# Prove $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is a homomorphism given by $([x], [y]) \to([x+2y], [y])$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is a homomorphism given by $([x], [y]) \to([x+2y], [y])$.

I don't know how to prove this because $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is NOT homomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ right? Then, how can $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ be homomorphic?

Comment: There is always a trivial homomorphism between groups.

Comment: That isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to prove it for each component.
\begin{align}
&\varphi_{11}:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z&
&x+4\Bbb Z\mapsto x+4\Bbb Z\\
&\varphi_{12}:\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z&
&y+6\Bbb Z\mapsto 2y+4\Bbb Z\\
&\varphi_{21}:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z&
&x+4\Bbb Z\mapsto 0+3\Bbb Z\\
&\varphi_{22}:\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z&
&y+6\Bbb Z\mapsto y+3\Bbb Z\\
\end{align}
In particular, $\varphi_{22}$ is the only group homomorphism making the following diagram commutative$\require{AMScd}$:
\begin{CD}
\Bbb Z@>y\mapsto y+3\Bbb Z>>\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\\
@VVV @|\\
\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z@>>\varphi_{22}>\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z
\end{CD}